# Не работает SVG SMIL в Firefox

Tags: svg

Захотел помочь в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/883948/308974) вопросе , я даже получилось что бы двигалась кисть по струнам, использовал анимацию SMIL и также убедился [здесь](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20smil) что эта техника поддерживается в Firefox но при проверке оказалось что нет.

**Подскажите где я ошибся ?**

Сразу скажу что SVG не особо люблю ...точнее вообще не люблю и это первое что я пробую сделать ...

**Применял Inkscape для получения path**

так как код не помещается я его поместил в [песочницу](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rZbGyG) но проблемный участок вот этот:

```html
<svg>
  <path d="" style="fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.92;">
    <animate attributeName="d" repeatCount="indefinite"
    from="m 33.335811,141.04875 c 0.04931,-0.0878 0.099,-0.17612 0.147859,-0.26437 -0.103596,-0.37932 -0.02299,-0.79015 0.360983,-1.00945 3.208733,-1.83475 6.855554,-3.86976 10.918064,-3.82865 0.310038,0.003 0.512973,0.41496 0.222349,0.54635 -1.723216,0.77769 -3.512749,1.44679 -5.179523,2.32697 -0.860559,0.45387 -1.714309,0.91892 -2.567046,1.3849 1.023722,-0.21644 2.010445,-0.53589 3.016727,-0.8363 1.500224,-0.44788 3.290037,-1.06197 4.99111,-0.66846 0.161208,0.0374 0.306003,0.27697 0.151053,0.37355 -1.461319,0.91199 -3.256167,1.60439 -4.88065,2.2637 -0.02878,0.0112 -0.05775,0.0212 -0.08658,0.0327 1.465614,-0.25365 2.899769,-0.54956 4.464663,0.0845 0.236824,0.0957 0.304673,0.46106 0.07389,0.53538 -1.754344,0.56574 -3.680879,0.95819 -5.544365,1.25629 -1.877887,0.29917 -3.541191,0.0488 -5.469365,-0.64888 -0.680566,-0.24633 -0.895841,-1.05684 -0.619332,-1.54869"
    to="m 34.244441,139.46707 c 0.10043,-0.007 0.201503,-0.0147 0.302059,-0.0227 0.259073,-0.2958 0.646117,-0.45541 1.040955,-0.25634 3.301316,1.66241 7.011472,3.57952 9.220107,6.98944 0.16867,0.26016 -0.06277,0.65681 -0.332776,0.48703 -1.599808,-1.00741 -3.14569,-2.13008 -4.799791,-3.03385 -0.853541,-0.46693 -1.712645,-0.92202 -2.571965,-1.37574 0.74566,0.73406 1.55678,1.3804 2.362824,2.05356 1.201706,1.00358 2.701876,2.15684 3.312938,3.79242 0.05782,0.15506 -0.06199,0.40805 -0.228061,0.33218 -1.567191,-0.71491 -3.135435,-1.82914 -4.58203,-2.81959 -0.02523,-0.0178 -0.04956,-0.0365 -0.07507,-0.0541 1.020653,1.08196 2.059173,2.11436 2.394486,3.76919 0.05096,0.2503 -0.216212,0.50859 -0.405594,0.3572 -1.440274,-1.15039 -2.83113,-2.54002 -4.10851,-3.92918 -1.286223,-1.40056 -1.99578,-2.92562 -2.478614,-4.91848 -0.170356,-0.70344 0.386576,-1.33041 0.94933,-1.37142"
    dur=".3s"
    fill="freeze"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда-то тут уже сталкивались с такой проблемой. Вам всего лишь то нужно дописать `0` перед `.3`(dur="0.3s").

Comment: thank you .. I did not know that the answer is very simple ...

Comment: @НикитаФаст, yeah, you should be attentive=)

Comment: I try to be considerate but SVG for me is a mystery covered in darkness